# A question regarding integration over $\varnothing$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

Does $\int_\varnothing f(x)dx = 0$ make any sense? Is one allowed to use $\varnothing$ this way?

Comment: With Lebesgue integration, that's perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Perhaps $\emptyset$ would be a better symbol...

Comment: I was thinking about Riemann integration, I don't know anything about Lebesgue integration.

Comment: @copper.hat I've been told by other users to use $\varnothing$ instead. It looks better as well in my opinion.

Comment: @David Riemann integrals are only over closed intervals. You can extend them to intervals of the form $[a, \infty)$, $(-\infty, b]$ by taking limits. So I think the answer is no, for Riemann integrals it makes no sense.

Comment: Ignore the other users :-).

Comment: Both $\varnothing$ and $\emptyset$ are perfectly fine. I prefer $\emptyset$, but there's no strong reason either way.

Comment: @NoahSchweber That would be $\{0\}$, no?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Derp, not my finest moment.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Well, now we know you're human ;)

Comment: Is there a reason that Riemann integrals aren't defined over open intervals?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom It's a formal thing. Open intervals aren't compact, so the partitioning becomes tricky. For $f:(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ bounded one can define $\int_{(a,b)} f$ as $\int_{[a,b]} f$ where $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are arbitrary, I suppose.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: the Riemann integral is defined over any Jordan-measurable (aka "contented") set, not just closed intervals.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Perhaps it can be generalized as you describe, but most analysis books I'm aware of explicitly define it on a closed interval.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: defining it over a closed interval does not in any way imply it can't be defined over more general sets. Perhaps you haven't seen the definition because you're an undergrad. In any case, your last comment ("most books I'm aware of...") in no way implies your first one ("Riemann integrals are **only** over closed intervals"). For a reference, if you're curious, see Zorich's Analysis II, Munkres's Analysis on Manifolds, or Loomis and Sternberg's Advanced Calculus.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Okay, fair enough, I stand corrected then.

Comment: I think in almost any context, if you wrote $\int_{\varnothing} f(x) \mathrm{d} x$ would at worst say, "Huh, that's an unusual thing to write", and then immediately interpret it as $0$. I would say regardless of whether it "makes sense" to Riemann-integrate over $\varnothing$, if you have reason to write it, go for it. Your reader will probably understand.

Answer (score 0):

The integral over an empty set makes perfect sense even with Riemann integration: note that the empty set ***is*** closed.

Comment: How can it be closed? My understanding is that a closed set is one that can be written $[\alpha,\beta]$. How can $\varnothing$ be considered close? Is there a more detailed definition of a closed set?

Comment: @David A closed *interval* looks like $[\alpha, \beta]$. There are several equivalent definitions of closed and open on the real line, but an important fact about *any* topological space is that both the whole space and $\varnothing$ are both open and closed.